# A solution for two search console property set up shows same meta verification code

Tags: google-search-console

I have two website properties created in google search console account and showing same meta verification code. What could be the reason behind this? How coudl I differentiate the two sites data separately by adding this same code.

Answer (score 1):

There is only ever one verification code for each Google Search Console account. The verification code allows Google to know that the site is authorized to show data to your Google Search Console account. Google does not use the verification code for site or property differentiation purposes. Google uses the domain name and URL to differentiate the properties within the same account.

It is perfectly normal to have the same verification code for both properties. If you try to verify additional domains in the same Google search console account, they will also have the same verification code.